# google play service and firebase App on older device issue

Tags: android, firebase, google-play-services

I've an Firebase App with following dependencies

```
// Play Services
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.0.2'

    // Firebase
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:0.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-common:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.2'
```

When I run the app on OS 4.4.2, I get an error as app is not working, I found that this is the issue with `com.google.android.gms` play-services when I installed the **com.google.android.gms 9.4.xx** I got error *This app requires newer Virson of OS*

**Question:** Is there any settings/dependencies should I use so that my Firebase should work on older devices as well please help in this case!

Answer (score 1):

@Crazy Coder

Just want to confirm if your device with API Level 17 had Google Play Services installed? If not, it is necessary to have a Google Play Services installed on your device in order for this to work.

Please also note that your Google Play Services should be version 9.4.0 or newer.

I hope this helps. Just let me know if you still have any other concern

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2s5h5.png

this is my app level gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.app.ids"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),   'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    }
    }
   dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.+'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.+'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.0'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.1'
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5'
compile fileTree(include: '*.jar', dir: 'libs')
compile files('libs/ksoap2-android-assembly-2.4-jar-with-dependencies.jar')
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
compile 'com.github.oliveiradev:image-zoom:0.1.0'
compile 'it.sephiroth.android.library.imagezoom:imagezoom:+'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.2.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.2.1'
compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.1+'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

this is my project level gradle file:

```
  buildscript {
  repositories {
    jcenter()
   }
   dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.5.0-beta2'
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha6'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
  }
  }
  allprojects {
  repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
  }
  }
  task clean(type: Delete) {
  delete rootProject.buildDir
   }
```

Comment: Yes Google Play Services installed on my device but upgrade is causing issues.

Comment: will I get Google Play Services 9.4.0 or newer compatible for my 4.4.2 OS?

Comment: @CrazyCoder chk this image this solution give by firebase team

Comment: No need to add google play service @Crazy Coder just update your google play service in your device

Comment: Thanks & I have checked that, but want to know would I face compatibility issue there, because from my _5.1 OS_ powered device I transferred  the apk to 4.4.2 OS device, but that raised issue _This app requires newer Virson of OS_

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120649/discussion-between-damini-mehra-and-crazy-coder).